# Git Commit adds line breaks that wasn't commited

Tags: vs-code, git

I've been working fine deploying profile permissions on git via VSC.
Recently I started to have some issues where I check the changes stage those, check again and see like 10 lines modified.
Then when i do the commit, Just before the commit is accepted,if I undo last commit and see the file, it changes and adds line breaks ending up with structure like this

```
<fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field
    >ObjectName.FieldName</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
```

This of course is a major issue since we lost tracking of the changes commited but I just can't seem to find a reason why this is ocurring and I end up when I do my PR with 5k+ lines of modification.

I've reinstalled VSC, Node to a stable versions. And this are my configurations for xml files.

```
{
    "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.advanced.enable-completion-statistics": true,
    "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.enable-semantic-errors": true,
    "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.13",
    "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true,
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "editor.foldingMaximumRegions": 50000,
    "xml.symbols.maxItemsComputed": 50000
}
```

Last 2 values I modified the standard I had of 5k since I thought that could be the issue. But it still the issue persists.

This seems to be happening only with profiles which makes me think this has to be something to do with large xml files but I can't figure out what.

UPDATE: It has to do something with hooks since when I do my commit on command line it detects correctly the lines but when I do it via the VSC button on source control pannel all hell break loose. But still have no idea exactly how to fix this.

Comment: sound like git hooks or some other plugins are in place that change those

Comment: Yeah, I messed around with some libraries when I tried to install the plugins for usage of vlocity but I don't know how to get back to the original state. I just re-installed VSC from scratch but no effect took place. 
If it helps, sometimes I also started getting Husky error. But I have no idea about hooks so I feel pretty lost but from what I found might be a Node version issue.

Comment: do you have a `package.json` file with `husky` to run on `pre-commit`?